# preg_match_all to find all words after a certain string

Tags: php, regex

I have the following string: `cache:search:amsterdam:hotel`

I want to have a `preg_match_all` to find the words `amsterdam` and `hotel` (in this case). I've done some looking around and came to:

```
preg_match_all( "/(?<=cache:search)(:/w*)/i", "cache:search:amsterdam:hotel", $matches )
```

I'm hoping to get $matches to have the values `amsterdam` and `hotel`, but so far I was only able to get `:amsterdam:hotel` or just `:amsterdam` in various tries. How can I get all words in between the parenthesis after the `cache:search`?

Comment: How about: `([\w:]+)` and then explode the first capturing group by a colon?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, once you have extracted `:amsterdam:hotel` you can easily split the string.

If you want to directly obtain separated words, you can use a `\G` based pattern:

```
preg_match_all('~(?:\G(?!\A)|cache:search):\K[^:]+~', $subject, $matches);
```

Where `\G` matches the position immediately after the previous match. *(Note that `\G` matches the start of the string too, that's why I added `(?!\A)`.)*

Answer (score 1):

Additionally to guys answers, in case you find it useful you can also use a regex like this:

```
(\w+):(\w+)$
```

**[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wE5rM9/1)**

```
preg_match_all('~(\w+):(\w+)$~', "cache:search:amsterdam:hotel", $matches);
```

Comment: If you already know that there are two words after `cache:search:`, it's indeed a more simple solution. You can also use a formatted string with: `sscanf($str, 'cache:search:%[^:]:%[^:]')`

Comment: Hey @CasimiretHippolyte, it's always a pleasure learning from you. Yes, I put the answer just for in case.

Answer (score 0):

You can just collect the last two words. This should work:

```
preg_match_all( "/(\w+):(\w+)$/i", "cache:search:amsterdam:hotel", $matches )
```

**Edit**:

In case there are more than two words you want to capture I would recommend `explode` instead:

```
$str = 'cache:search:amsterdam:hotel';
$matches = explode(':', substr($str, 13));
```

Comment: Weston, this matches the last 3 words, 'search', 'amsterdam' and 'hotel'. I know I can cut up that array, but I'm looking for everything after the 'cache:search' as separate words...

Comment: There, should only take the last two words now!

Comment: Weston, though this indeed is a solution for the given example, it was just an example. I don't know how many words are after the first two, interesting solution... I'll check how this performs over the preg_match

Comment: This is by far the fastest way to do it, but I don't really like the fixed '13' in there, so that would take some math as well which makes it about the same perfomance as the array_splice method elsewhere on this page

Comment: @patrick If the first word is always 'cache' and it's only the second that changes length, just substitute the `13` with this and it will be faster than calling array_splice `strpos($str, ':', 6) + 1`. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

A way to do this without a preg_match is this:

```
$matches = array_splice( ( explode( ':', 'cache:search:amsterdam:hotel' ) ), 2 );
```

I compared this to the accepted answer (the preg_match_all), that takes 56% longer to execute. The question was a regexp, so that will remain the accepted answer, but I wanted to post this alternative as well for people that come across the same problem